# How to make a condition that checks if value equals 1 or 0 without resulting in a boolean evaluation in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I'm making an API and in one of the endpoints the variable user_type that can only be a 0 or a 1

```
api/user?user_type=0 || api/user?user_type=1
```

Inside my controller i check if the variable equals to one of those two values, the problem is that the comprobation results in a boolean one, and if in the endpoint i add a text value for user_type results in true because the variable exists.

Is there any way of evaluating without triggering a boolean result? Something like this:

```
if($variable != 0 && $variable != 1){ return true } //It should be false if $variable == 'text' and true if variable == 0 or 1
```

Comment: Have you heard the good word about our lord `===` and our savior `!==`? Edit: I really don't know what is it about avoiding booleans.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp?rq=1

Comment: i guess you can use filtervar with parameter `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` which would returns true for "1", "true", "on" and "yes" ,returns false otherwise. On top of that `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` since it would **remove all characters** except digits, plus and minus sign or just use plain old to compare === or !==

Answer (score 0):

PHP8 satisfies your condition without any modification. Or you can use one of the below conditions -
0 and 1 within quotes.
OR
Check with ! == and ===